I have an older model Whirlpool gas dryer that I am replacing the motor in. The part number is 3391888. How do I rewire it for the old wiring?
I got the replacement part that now replaces the old part, it is a 279827.  The new part has a wiring harness which the old part does not have.  I need the instructions for how to wire the dryer to the new motor as the instructions did not come with the new motor.  I have contacted the company where I  purchased it but they don't seem to understand the issue.
